# 2 Different DropDownList in the same position selected by radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to have 2 dropdownlist in the same position. One dropdownlist will show when a radiobutton is chosen.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean exactly? if you want a select-able dropdownlist you can build one using html and javascript, you can even have your dropdownlist based on category

Comment: Hi, for example. I have radiobuttons. if user clicks rdbtn1, dropdownlist1 will show up and if user clicks rdbtn2, dropdownlist2 will appear. but this two ddl will be on the same exact position.

Comment: yes its possible, you can even manage it in your code-behind, you are using webform right? include some code i give you the solution

Comment: `<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn1" runat="server"  Text="OutPatient" GroupName="patientType" OnCheckedChanged="rdbtn1_CheckedChanged" />
&nbsp;<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn2" runat="server" Text="InPatient" GroupName="patientType" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Patient ID:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: for the rdbtn click `if(rdbtn1.Checked == true){
                DropDownList1.Visible = true;
                DropDownList2.Visible = false;
            
            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList1.Visible = false;
                DropDownList2.Visible = true;
            }`

Comment: yes, i am usig webform

Comment: I recommend reading this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: oops, sorry.. i'm fairly new but i've upvoted it. Thank you once again!

Comment: It's alright! To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 approach, one using `JQuery` playing with `CSS` and `html elements`:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" class="Here you position it">
<select id="ddlFirst" class="Same Position class" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlSecond" class="Same Position class" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

Here is your JQuery:

```
<script>
$("#btn").click(function() {
   var radio = $("#radio").val();
   var ddlFirst;
   var ddlSecond;
   if(!radio)
       {
         $("#radio").css("visibility", "Hidden");
         $("#ddlFirst").css("visibility", "Visible");

         $("#ddlFirst").on("click", function() {
            var ddlFirst = $('#ddlFirst').find(":selected").text();
            if(!ddlFirst)
              {
                //same rotation
              }
         });
       }
});
</script>
```

Then you can send the values using `ajax`

Second Approach is using `asp.net tags` and manage them in your code-behind, you should fix the `CSS` yourself tho.

in your `page_load`:

```
//visiblity
rdbtn1.Visible = true;
DropDownList1.Visible = false;
DropDownList1.Visible = false;

if(rdbtn1.Checked == true)
   { 
     DropDownList1.Visible = true;
     rdbtn1.Visible = false;
   } 
else if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue != 0)
   { 
     DropDownList1.Visible = false;
     DropDownList2.Visible = true; 
   }
else if(DropDownList2.SelectedValue != 0)
   { 
     //Totally get all your ur controls hidden in this state
     DropDownList2.Visible = false;
   }
```